# Getting objects from elastic search in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, express, elasticsearch

I'm using nodejs/express for a webapp and storing data in elastic search.  I would like to put something like the user profile in elastic search, and when I pull it out call methods on it.  I'm used to Java/C# so I would expect to do something like

```
var user = new User(elasticSearchResult)
user.getUserRoles()
```

The constructor would parse the data and the class would contain all the methods I need.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

you need this https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch
Then you can create function for that User class as

```
User.getUserRoles = function(){
client.search({
   index: ....,
   type: ....
   body: {
       query: {
        ....
       }
   }
}).then(function (resp) {
  //Handle records return here
}, function (err) {
  //handle error here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this for my user class

```
var proto = User.prototype;
function User(){}

proto.setRoles = function(roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
};

proto.fromJson = function(json) {
    if(json._source) {  // From ElasticSearch query
        this.roles = json._source.roles;
    }
};
exports.User = User;
```

And in my calling class

```
var user = new UserClass.User();
db.searchForUser(user.email, function(err, success) {
    if (success.hits.total == 1) {
        var userFromDb = success.hits.hits[0];
        user.fromJson(userFromDb);
        return done(null, user);
    }
});
```

and if anyone is wondering, here is my searchForUser method

```
exports.searchForUser = function (email, callback) {
    var qryObj = {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "email": email
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    };
    client.search ({index:'myindex', type:'user', body: qryObj}, callback);
};
```